# Firefox - "This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave" message when using "beforeunload" event

Tags: javascript, firefox, onbeforeunload

**EDIT**: Managed to fix it. See answer.

I attached a "beforeunload" event listener to the window in order to change some general styles right before the user leaves the page. However, Firefox interprets this as me wanting to query the user on whether they want to leave so it triggers an alert modal with the "This page is asking you to confirm that you want to..." message.

Is there any way I can prevent this and just let the user leave the page?

I tried using `e.preventDefault()` to no avail.

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (e) => {
     e.preventDefault();
     document.getElementById("loading-screen").children[0].style.display = "none";
     document.getElementById("loading-screen").style.zIndex = "10000000000";
     document.getElementById("loading-screen").style.opacity = "1";
});
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue ..? Maybe you've more than one listener for beforeunload?

Comment: @Teemu Strange. This is just the one. When I comment it out, the issue is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it in the meantime.

Removing `e.preventDefault()` did it. I'm not sure why Firefox behaves this way.

Comment: The browser prompt doesn't occur in FF77.0.1, with or without `e.preventDefault`.